# keycloak-js initialization failed because an ancestor violates the Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-javascript

I have a NGINX (1.14.1) which forwards /auth request to Keycloak (14.0.0) running in a cloud.

Here is the NGINX configuration in /etc/nginx/conf.d/my.domain.biz.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.domain.biz;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name my.domain.biz;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.biz/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.biz/privkey.pem;
  location /auth {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://my.domain.biz/";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-src https://my.domain.biz/; frame-ancestors https://my.domain.biz/; object-src https://my.domain.biz/;";
  }
}
```

I'm able to create a realm and a public client in the Keycloak's admin console at https://my.domain.biz/auth/. I'm able to list the endpoints from https://my.domain.biz/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration

also, I have updated the following two values in security defenses of the realm settings,

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://my.domain.biz
Content-Security-Policy: frame-src https://my.domain.biz/; frame-ancestors https://my.domain.biz/; object-src https://my.domain.biz/;
```

I have a React webapp with [keycloak-js 14.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-js) running on my laptop at http://localhost:8044/, which I want to authenticate with the Keycloak running in the cloud. The Keycloak client is initialized with the following `keycloak.json`,

```
{
  "realm": "myrealm",
  "auth-server-url": "https://my.domain.biz/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "my-pkce",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

and the React code snippet,

```
  const kc = new Keycloak('/keycloak.json');
  ...
  await kc.init({
    onLoad: 'login-required',
    pkceMethod: 'S256',
    enableLogging: true
  });
```

When accessed the webapp at http://localhost:8044/, it didn't redirect to the Keycloak's login page, with an error shown in the Chrome browser console:

```
Refused to frame 'https://my.domain.biz/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

and only one line is logged in the NGINX's `/var/log/nginx/access.log`,

```
"GET /auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html HTTP/1.1" 404 2032 "http://localhost:8044/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Do you have any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Try to use also `checkLoginIframe: false` in `kc.init`. BTW `ALLOW-FROM` directive in `X-Frame-Options` is obsolete directive https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Yes, `checkLoginIframe: false` solved the problem. I have revert the Content-Security-Policy configuration from NGINX and Keyclock's realm settings.

Thank you!

Comment: @JanGaraj How can we set this value if we are running keycloak as kubernetes pod. Is there any environment variable. I tried to search but could not find. Please suggest

Comment: Thanks to your question I added "Content-Security-Policy" to my nginx config.   

It is not mentioned in the official docs, but without this header keycloak does not work behind the proxy.

Answer (score 14):

In the recently versions of keycloak /auth param has been removed. so your init parameter configuration should look like this:

"auth-server-url": "https://my.domain.biz"

tested with the following stack:

angular version: 13.13.11

keycloakjs: 18

keycloak server: 18.0.1 (bitnami docker image)

I hope it helps

Comment: after 2-3 hours i find this is the issue. remove `/auth` and it started loading the app.
But when the login screen from keyclock says page not found

Answer (score 13):

After several painful hours, I discovered that spelling the Realm Name incorrectly on your frontend app can also lead to the same error. Note that Realm Names are case-sensitive.

Comment: It was a custom `REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT` env in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I solved without /auth suffix. for today, you shouldnt write "/auth" suffix path.