# Keycloak error on console " violating Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I am trying to integrate React with keycloak.
But I am getting this error on console

```
    Refused to frame 'http://localhost:8080/'
 because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

This is the keycloak file

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
const keycloak = Keycloak({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
  realm: "keycloak-react-auth",
  clientId: "react",
});

export default keycloak;
```

Version of install of keycloak and react:

*"@react-keycloak/web": "^3.4.0",

"react": "^17.0.1",*

I also saw that in this  [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68509296/keycloak-js-initialization-failed-because-an-ancestor-violates-the-content-secur), the solution can be if you use this parameter `checkLoginIframe: false`, but TypeScript says that this attribute is not recognised in the Keycloak object

Comment: That looks like you are trying to login in the iframe. Generally, iframing should be disabled for the auth. Also use PKCE flow for SPA app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the Realm Configuration -> Security Defences -> Content-Security-Policy

```
 frame-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self' http://localhost:3000; object-src 'none';
```

Comment: That will decrease a security, so I would say it is a work around, but not solution.

Comment: Beware of clickjacking attacks. However, it anwers the original question, so I give you an upvote 

Comment: In development, adding GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false in .env file worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the environment variable `KC_HOSTNAME` was set to a different address from the one I was trying to access the keycloak web console.

If you are running keycloak in a container, add this to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=localhost
```