# keycloak not working with nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, keycloak, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

We've deployed [nginx ingress controller](https://helm.nginx.com/) without changing any default value. Now when we are trying to access keycloak service using this nginx proxy it's responding but not able to access admin console. It keeps 'loading the admin console'.

here is the configuration of keycloak:
service and deployment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/latest/kubernetes-examples/keycloak.yaml
ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: keycloak.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: keycloak
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Due to unchanged default value `server-snippets` and `location-snippets` are disabled. But if it is mandatory then please provide suggestion along with it.
Any help would be appreciated.

[EDIT] `Service.type` is already set to `ClusterIP`

**`ERROR in console:`** `Refused to frame 'http://keycloak.mydomain.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".`

Here is the describe output of ingress:

```
Name:             keycloak
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          <AWSLoadBalancerIP>.elb.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                          Path  Backends
  ----                          ----  --------
  keycloak.prod-pl.qritive.com  
                                /   keycloak:8080 (172.24.28.112:8080)
Annotations:                    <none>
Events:                         <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the env var : **KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME** & **PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING** i was also trying to use Nginx ingress.

Check below configuration once

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.0
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: POSTGRES
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: postgres
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: keycloak
        - name: DB_USER
          value: root
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name : KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT
          value : "80"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT
          value: "443"
        - name : KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
          value : keycloak.harshmanvar.tk #replace with ingress URL
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: https
          containerPort: 8443
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /auth/realms/master
            port: 8080
```

[My GitHub ref](https://github.com/harsh4870/Keycloack-postgres-kubernetes-deployment)

Comment: thanks for replying. I have tested the configuration as you suggested but still it doesn't work. Also I have append the exact error to the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72805943/5525824

Comment: It may work but will lead to security breach.

Comment: This certainly doesn't work, there is no ingress in that repo as welll.

Comment: that's the normal ingress mentioned above you have to create or use i have shared the necessary config for deployment and service.

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the yaml file of keycloak service, its type is Loadbalancer. Change it to clusterIP and then deploy it. also make sure that

```
kubectl describe ingress <NAME>
```

connect the ingress to the respective pod port. if not then run the following command to see the problem

`kubectl describe service keycloak`

Comment: @Najmus_Siraj I've updated ingress describe output in question.

Comment: is it working fine now? the ingress shown by describe is not the same as your ingress yaml file

Comment: I was trying with different annotations. so there may be a diff. describe output.
But still it's not working. Can you suggest any reference.