# Configuration Nginx from Keycloak

Tags: nginx, keycloak

I'm having trouble setting up a Keycloak environment for production.

After running my Keycloak instance through Docker Compose, when accessing my URL that redirects to the Keycloak hosted on my VPS, I am facing the following error:

```
Refused to frame 'http://keycloack.aterro.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".
```

My Nginx settings are:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name keycloak.aterro.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloack.aterro.com.br/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloack.aterro.com.br/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://144.126.[omited]:9999;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Adicione a diretiva CSP aqui
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.aterro>
    }
}
```

My URL Application: keycloak.aterro.com
My Keycloak Application in VPS: http://144.126.[omited]:9999

Can you help me?

I expected to access the url, when I clicked on Administration Console, I logged in

Comment: These answers look promising but I haven't tested them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72805440/keycloak-error-on-console-violating-content-security-policy-directive-frame

Comment: But, i don't accesse the admin console.
The inferace is block because the error.

Comment: Did you try this solution: 

In my case, the environment variable KC_HOSTNAME was set to a different address from the one I was trying to access the keycloak web console.

If you are running keycloak in a container, add this to your Dockerfile:

ENV KC_HOSTNAME=localhost